# Google Maps API full screen in SWIFT3

Tags: ios, xcode, api, google-maps, swift3

This is the current code, after making the edits suggested, it no longer shows a marker on the map for Sydney Australia

class LocateVC: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //override func loadView() {
    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86  , longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.mapView.bounds, camera: camera)
    self.mapView = mapView

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView
  }
```

}

Output

This is the screen that loads
[image: This is the screen that loads]

And no marker on Sydney Australia
[image: And no marker on Sydney Australia]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are setting `mapview` to main `view` of `ViewController`

**So Change your these two lines**

```
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
view = mapView
```

**With:**

```
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.mapView.bounds, camera: camera)
self.mapView = mapView
```

Comment: ok, did that.  This now gives me fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when loading the map

Comment: @JadeReynolds Check your `mapView` outlet is properly connected with `LocateVC` if not then connect it.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that, works now, thank you very much

Comment: @JadeReynolds Welcome mate :)

Comment: although interstingly it no longer shows the marker on the map, just loads a google map view, any thoughts?

Comment: @JadeReynolds Edit your post with current code and show me screen shot of output.

Comment: @JadeReynolds Try like this `marker.map = self.mapView`

Comment: still the same :(

Comment: @JadeReynolds Don't get it why marker is not showing. Are you having any other code accept this one.

Comment: no, this is the only code on the map view screen.  and marker worked ok before changing the code to self.mapview as above

Comment: @JadeReynolds Try once putting the marker code in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`

Comment: ok seems to be working now, the pin is now showing, but the camera does not default to that location.  This is my current code.

Comment: I have also doesn't get why it is not showing annotation

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Nirav is almost there

here what I did:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class AddressMapController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var map123: GMSMapView! // this is linked to a UIView in storyboard

    var currentLocation: CLLocation! //this is passed from the main controller

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let lat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
        let long = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat  , longitude: long, zoom: 12)

        // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
        let currentLocation_Marker = GMSMarker()
        currentLocation_Marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        currentLocation_Marker.title = "My Current Location"
        currentLocation_Marker.snippet = "I am here now"
        currentLocation_Marker.map = map123

        self.map123.camera = camera
    }
}
```

hope it will help somebody in the future